# Ajax - How To Get Access Token From URL After Registration

Tags: javascript, ajax, token, axios

I am using Axios to Signup to our server. Which is returning fine now. However, I do not know how to retrieve the `access token` from a separate url.

The signup request looks like this:

```
  let settings = {
      url: "https://api.dev.etcetc.com/user/signup",
      data: {
        Username : username,
        Password : password },
      method: 'POST',
      headers : {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
      },
      transformRequest: [(data) => {
        return JSON.stringify(data);
      }]
  };
```

The access token is to be retrieved from a url like:

```
https://api.dev.etcetc.com/token
```

Do I run another Axios request( this time GET instead of POST)? I have not been given any info on how to or whether to provide any config for this `access token` call.

Comment: As per my experience with token based authentication, either the token details are returned with the first ajax call itself or some identifier/token is returned that will be needed to make another ajax request like your /token api to get the session token. You may need to look into documentation for the information.

Comment: @devilfox thank you, that does make sense. All I know is that its suppose to be an 'endpoint'

Answer (score 0):

maybe the url will give you a code, you can use the code to get the token in you java or php code with the apt which Axios provide

Comment: Its javascript, and yes, the access token is to be taken from that address.